# AppleScript Editor record doesn't work

Tags: macos, mac, applescript

I have opened the AppleScript Editor and pressed Record button.

Then I run TextEdit, create a file and put some text there.

When I click Stop button in AppleScript Editor, nothing was recorded, the window is blank.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all (or even many) applications are recordable -- if the app doesn't jump through the right hoops, nothing you do in it will show up in the recording.  This does rather limit the usefulness of AppleScript's recording capability...